# How to split repeated chars and numbers with preg_split?

Tags: php, design-patterns, preg-split

I'm trying to solve some problem and I need to split repeated chars and all integers

```
$code = preg_split('/(.)(?!\1|$)\K/', $code);
```

I tried this one, but it separate and not repeated chars and not repeated integers , I need only chars

I have a string 'FFF86C6'

I need an array `(FFF, 86, C, 6)`;

with pattern `'/(.)(?!\1|$)\K/' returns (FFF, 8, 6, C, 6)`

Do you have any idea how to make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex with [`preg_match_all`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
([A-Za-z])(\1*)|\d+
```

It looks for a letter, followed by some number of the same character, or some digits. By using `preg_match_all` we find all matches in the string. Usage in PHP:

```
$string = "FFF86CR6";
$pieces = preg_match_all('/([A-Za-z])(\1*)|\d+/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output:

```
Array (
  [0] => FFF
  [1] => 86
  [2] => C
  [3] => R
  [4] => 6 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/4YUcn)

Comment: Thanks a lot, maybe you know how to add ')' and '(' to this pattern?  So if there are bracket in string it will also appear in array as single element. Those patterns are a bit painful for me :(

Comment: @OlgaKriukova can you give me an example of what you mean?

Comment: if string 'FFF3RF(5' after preg_match_all :  array('FFF',  '3',  'R',  'F',  '(',  '5');

Comment: @OlgaKriukova just add a character class for `(` and `)` to the regex. See https://3v4l.org/8Vl5a